# Magento 2 Module Observer Sequence order and Sales Order Event

Tags: magento2, event-observer, dependency, sequence

We have two modules which fire the same event checkout_submit_all_after.But i need to give a preference for this , i tried giving sequence in module b but it won't work.For ex Module A and Module B triggers the same event, but module B triggers first, my requirement is to trigger Module A and after Module B , is there any way i can do this. And what are the events triggers when order is placed through cron jobs, I have used `checkout_submit_all_after`, does this event fires if the order is placed through crons?.

Please give me any solution for to go forward.
Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first, question, you want to trigger `Module A` module observer then fire observer of  `Module B`.

Then below is my solution is of this case.

Disable `Module B` using **xml** code.

Then Create [around plugin](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) the method  `ModuleA_ObserverClass::execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)` of `Observer of module A`.

And on that around Plugin `PluginClass::aroundExecute()` execute original  `ModuleA_ObserverClass::execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)` and 
using `$proceed(\ModuleA_ObserverClass $subject,\Callable ,$observer)`
And after running of origina method ,  add  new method to `PluginClass`.

And on this new method, copy all code of `ModuleB: execute`  and run after `$proceed($observer)`.

### Step1: Disable Observer of `Module B`

```
<event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
    <observer name="{ModuleB_Observer_Classs}" instance="{observerClassNameOfModuleB}" />
</event>
```

Assume above one is observer declaration of ModuleB. First, we have to disable this observer.

Let's create An `events.xml` at your custom module and disable this by XML node `disabled`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
    <!-- Note that observer name should be same  of Module B observer -->
        <observer name="{ModuleB_Observer_Classs}" disabled="true" />
    </event>
</config>
```

### Step2: Create around plugin on ModuleA_ObserverClass::execute()

Create di.xml and declare the around plugin for `ModuleA_ObserverClass::execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"> 
    <type name="ModuleA_ObserverClass">
        <plugin name="ModuleA_ObserverClass_My_plugin" sortOrder="10" type="{PluginClass}"/>
    </type>     
</config>
```

**And Plugin code:**

```
<?php

namespace {Namespace};


class {PluginClass} {

    public function aroundExecute(
      \ModuleA_Observer_Classs $subject,
       callable $proceed,
       \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer    
   ){
        //This code run original Merthod
        $proceed($observer);
        $this->replicatedMethodExecuteofObseverOfModuleB($observer);
    }

    public function replicatedMethodExecuteofObseverOfModuleB($observer)
    {
        // Copy all code of `ModuleA_ObserverClass::execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)`
        // and paste here
    }
}
```